# Bigint class operator

Tags: c++, class, c++11

Please check out this code and tell me why is the operator += only works if the numbers have the same size when i tried `x += z;` `i` got `345678`.

I think the problem is `int for (i = 0; i <= len - 1; i++)` loop. I tried to fix it but I wasn't successful. Any solutions?

Header file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Mint {
public:

    Mint();
    Mint(int);
    Mint (const char  *s);
    string afficher();
    Mint operator+=(const Mint &rhs); //returns mint + rhs
    Mint operator+(const Mint &rhs);
private:
    vector<char> num;
};
```

Source file.

```
#include "Mint.h"
#include <string.h>

Mint::Mint()
{
    num.push_back(0);
}
Mint::Mint(int n)
{
    while(n!=0)
    {
        num.push_back(n%10);
        n = n/10;
    }
}
Mint::Mint(const char* s)
{
    int i = 0 ;
    for(i=strlen(s)-1;i>=0;i--)
    num.push_back(s[i] - '0');
}
string Mint::afficher(){
    string s="";
    int i;
    for(i=num.size()-1;i>=0;i--)
        s += char('0'+num[i]);
    return s;
}
Mint Mint::operator+=(const Mint &rhs) {
    unsigned int len = num.size();
    char carry = 0;

    if (len > rhs.num.size())
        len = rhs.num.size();

    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= len - 1; i++)
    {
        char result = num[i] + rhs.num[i] + carry;
        num[i] = result % 10;
        carry = result / 10;
    }

    while (carry)
    {
        if (i < num.size())
        {
            num[i] += carry;
            if (num[i] >= 10)
            {
                num[i] -= 10;
                i++;
            }
            else
                carry = 0;
        }
        else {
            num.push_back(carry);
            carry = 0;
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
Mint Mint::operator+(const Mint &rhs){
    Mint result;
    result = *this;
    return result+=rhs;
}
```

`main` file.

```
#include "Mint.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;  

int main()
{
    Mint x="123456",z="22222222222222222222",f;
    Mint a = "655478461469974272005572";
    Mint b = 8;
    x += z;
    f = x + z;
    cout << x.afficher()<<endl;

}
```

Comment: What do you see when you run it in the debugger?

Comment: if len == 0 , then len -1 might become the max value of unsigned int

Comment: `operator +=` should be returning a *reference* to the current object, not a new object.  It should be: `Mint& Mint::operator+=(const Mint &rhs)`

Comment: see the operator does works but the problem is it doesn't go thru the entire number here is an example  22222222222222222222 +=  123456  only returns 345678 instead of 22222222222222345678

Comment: So you're asking us to debug your own program?  Seriously, debugging your own code is part of learning how to write programs.

Comment: i know sorry ill try again

Comment: @user259584 Also, to debug easily, your test data should be simple.  Why test strings that are 20 or so characters in length?  Try a 3 or 4 character length number so that you can more easily track what is going wrong.  If it doesn't work with 3 characters, it certainly won't work with a 20 character string.

Comment: You need to resize the `num` vector to the larger of the two sizes.

Comment: @user259584:  3 or 4 be blowed.  Try `auto one=Mint(1); one+=Mint(11);`

Comment: Minor nit: `for (i = 0; i <= len - 1; i++)` is more idiomatically written as `for (i = 0; i < len ; ++i)`.

Answer (score 0):

I've now written big integer packages three times. One thing that helps me a great deal is to picture doing arithmetic by hand. Try it!

In the case of `+=` here, the problem occurs for something like 123 += 4567. The code looks at the length of both arrays, sees that the larger one is 4, and walks off the end of the first one, which only has three elements. So don't adjust `len` to `rhs.num.size()`.

Instead, add another loop in `operator+=`, between the two that are there: while there's a carry and `i` is less than `rhs.size()`, add `rhs[i]` and `carry` and push the sum into `*this`. Once the code has handled all of `rhs`, it should fall through to the final loop to handle any remaining carries.